# SP Online, can I add my ViewField value to SP.View.viewFields with JSOM?

Tags: list-view, jsom, view, viewfields

I need to add dissappeared ViewField to my List view (Calendar). it was before, but was dropped after I switched default view to another, and then returned back (I swutched my view back to 'Default View', but now it does not contain needed field)

I see something here [on stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160373/add-field-to-splist-default-view), but not sure it is JSOM.
Can I use JSOM to do something same? There is too little documentaion about it..

Maybe somebody did the same before. Something like this:

```
    var web = clientContext.get_web();

    var listCollection = web.get_lists();
    var list = listCollection.getByTitle("Rooms");
    var viewCollection = list.get_views();

    // CSOM here..
    SPView view = list.DefaultView;
    view.ViewFields.Add("My_Room_Name");
    view.Update();
    // ..

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {

    }, onFail);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there, instead of adding fields individually, you can add it as a collection.

Modify it from below sample:

```
var viewCollection = list.get_views();
var view = list.get_defaultView();

var viewFields = ["Title","Description","My_Room_Name"];  
view.set_viewFields(viewFields);  
view.Update();

context.load(view);
context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
        console.log("sucess changing viewFields");
    },  
    function(sender,args){  
        console.log(args.get_message());  
});
```

Reference - [SP.ViewCreationInformation.viewFields property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj244926.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Great that this field is not readonly. Thanks much Gautam, I haven't used collection but this worked for me:

```
function addViewField() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = clientContext.get_web();
    var listCollection = web.get_lists();
    var list = listCollection.getByTitle("Rooms List");

    var defaultView = list.get_defaultView();
    var defaultViewFields = defaultView.get_viewFields();

    defaultViewFields.add("Conference_Room");

    defaultView.update();
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        console.log("ViewField added");
    }, onFail);
}
```