# Add View Library Link to View in Document Library (or Go to Location of File Link)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I wonder if there is a simple solution for the requirement to have a link to the location of the file in a custom view of a document library?

I have a view that shows all files of a library without folders and sorts the newest on top. Often there is the need to jump to the location of a file. This is only possible by opening the file properties and using the breadcrump in this properties view. On site search level the results typically have a link in the flyout menu that sais "View Library". I don´t understand why this is not a standard(?).

I read something about "FileDirRef" but cannot seem to find information on how to use this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there are better ways to do this, but there are definitely *other* ways to do this.

Here's a possible approach, using **CSR** + **jslink** (basically adding **FileDirRef** and transforming it into a hyperlink):

1) add the FileDirRef field to the view

```
        string viewFieldToAdd = "FileDirRef";
        List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
        View view = list.DefaultView;
        context.Load(list);
        context.Load(list.Fields);
        context.Load(view);
        context.Load(view.ViewFields);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        if(!view.ViewFields.Any(x => x == viewFieldToAdd))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Adding viewfield: " + viewFieldToAdd);
            view.ViewFields.Add(viewFieldToAdd);
            view.Update();
            context.ExecuteQuery();
        }
```

2) open the list view
e.g. http://.../Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx

3) enter edit mode by adding **?ToolPaneView=2** to the url,

e.g. http://.../Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?ToolPaneView=2

4) go into webpart edit mode and paste the jslink url, ensuring the destination js file exists, e.g.
**~sitecollection/Style Library/csr/FolderLink.js**

5) write the csr script (FolderLink.js)

```
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
  Templates: {
        Fields: {
           'FileDirRef': {'View':function(ctx) {
                  if(ctx.CurrentItem.FileDirRef != null)
                  {
                      var url = ctx.CurrentItem.FileDirRef;
                      return String.format('<a href="{0}">{1}</a>', url, url);
                  }
           }}
       }
  }
});
```

Comment: Question to 1): Where to put the mentioned code? In a script editor on that same page?

Comment: so the idea is to add a view field that normally isn't available in the UI. it's a one-time execution that you need to run either server side or client side (jsom, csom, etc.). in the example I'm running a console application with csom. you can try js instead. example: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/240786/sp-online-can-i-add-my-viewfield-value-to-sp-view-viewfields-with-jsom